# javascript canvas.toDataURL() works without generating the canvas visually

Tags: javascript, php, html, dompdf

I'm trying to create a pdf file with dompdf and I need to convert a html canvas to img and send to pdf. It works fine if you come to page where you have the canvas and click to generate the pdf, but now I need do the same thing but with cron, without access the page.
In my test using canvas.toDataURL to convert the canvas to base64 and to send it to pdf, running cron script without access to the page and render canvas on screen, the pdf didn't show anything. Its possible use toDataURL() without rendering the image on screen? Or I have to use another function to send the canvas image to pdf?

Comment: toDataURL is method of canvas api and if there is no canvas then this method is not going to available.

Comment: @deepak canvas is on the page, but is not rendered on the screen because i running a cron script, and this way, the pdf img its empty, just work if access the page and wait canvas to be complete

Comment: Hello @fehcps and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve